# Regular expressions in typography check

Tags: regex, typography

Good day, everyone!

To start, I am a professional translator/localizer/interpreter, so I face certain difficulties sometimes when addressing issues related to regex or something similar. Do bear with me, please :)

This is my current setting:

- translation of short medical articles;
- localization of an app.
  These articles are published directly in the app, so we need to pre-test them against certain typographic rules in order to avoid misalignment.

For I am a new team lead, I decided to automate this process using regex.
But I am stuck for I do not really understand if I am right or wrong.

This is what I came up with:

- non-breaking space before em dash, whitespace after em dash:
  `^[\xA0]+(—[\s]+)+$`
- en dash in numbers range (15–20 or 2001–2016): `^[0-9]+(–[0-9]+)+$`
- non-breaking spaces between numbers and words (15 children, week  4):
  `^([\d]+((\xA0))+[\w]+)` and `^[\w]+((\xA0)+[\d])+$`
- lists have to start with en dashes with the following whitespace:
  `(?(?=\S)(\-)|([\s]+[\w]+[\d]))+[\s]+[\w]+[\s]+.[[:punct:]]$`

I've tried to run these expressions on Regex101, everything seems normal, but I would love to understand if there is something to improve (and I believe, there certainly IS some room for improvement).

Thank you for your suggestions and help!

EDIT #1: This is not about the programming language, we will use these expressions in a QA app that allows checking translation memories against these rules.

EDIT #2: I've tested regex against our translation memory; it certainly doesn't work for lists - the regex doesn't show the error if there is no space between em dash and the following word;
and it works fine for a non-breaking space before en dash, but no reaction for the whitespace after en dash.

Comment: You should first check what regex engine the QA app uses. .NET expressions might not work with Python `re` supported ones, or they may work quite differently. What you use by default at regex101 is PCRE. Also, since you say the patterns work for you online, try them in your app. If there is any issue, come back after trying to fix.

Comment: well, the app has some built-in default regex rules, so I may copy-paste them in here. I believe this is not Python.
This is, for example, a triple letter check: `([a-vx-z])\1\1`

Comment: This a pattern using backreferences, so it is not RE2. It can be Python,  .NET, and a lot of others.

Comment: I've found this information: "The regular expression engine in QA Distiller uses the Perl Compatible Regular Expressions library." Is this it?

Comment: Ok, it is PCRE. Now, what is the problem with the regexps? You just posted them without indicating the issue. SO is about solving issues. Without them, the post is off-topic.

Comment: I just want to know if I am right or wrong :) is this still off-topic?

Comment: Yes, because we are not here to guess if anything works for someone else. It is you who should tell us what is wrong with them.

Comment: @AlexanderMarkevitch why don't you test it by giving representative sample inputs?

Comment: I've tested it several minutes ago and updated the question.